# Is it possible to use a WP7 device for development without syncing it with my development computer?

Tags: macos, windows-phone-7, registration

I currently sync my WP7 phone with my Mac, but I'm developing apps for it using my Windows partition.  Can I register it as a development device without syncing it on Windows?  It only seems to correctly handle syncing to one computer.

Clarification: I'd like the phone to not be set up as a sync device in the Zune software, because I don't want to accidentally have Zune sync my stuff instead of Windows Phone Connector on my Mac partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can deploy your app without syncing with the machine.  Just use the WPConnect.exe tool in the SDK.  Zune is smart enough to figure this out as well.

Comment: I'll need to temporarily sync my phone with Zune to use the Developer Registration Tool to register it in the first place, right?